# How to seperate the Model and View effectively for a tree-structured objects data model?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mfc

I'm developing a MFC application using MVC pattern. I use the MFC Dialog class as controller and a model class for the model,  a view class that holds the model class as a member for the view. The data in the model is organized in a tree structure, as displayed in this diagram:

[image: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FOJt.png>.]

In the diagram, the capital letter stands for a class name, so the data in the model is a tree of objects, each of which contains many data member, including the reference to the sub-object, like pointer of sub-object or array of sub-objects

But the problem is that when the view display or update the data in the model on the UI, it need to access the data members of every node object on every level, which requires including head files of those node objects so as to retrieve their data members. So the method of Drawing UI in the cpp file of the View class looks like this:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
#include "D.h"
#include "E.h"
#include "F.h"
#include "G.h"
void View::Draw(CDC *pDC)
{
      A a= Model.A; 
      B b1=A.b1; 
      B b2=A.b2;
      for (int i=0; i<b1.arrayofC.size; i++)
      {
           C c=b1.arrayofC[i];
           int length=c.getlength();
           int j=c.arrayofD.size;
           while (j>0)
           {
              D d=c.arrayofD[j];
              CString Name=d.Name;
              ...
              j--;
           }
           ....
      }
      for (int i=0; i<b2.arrayofC.size;i++)
      {
           C c=b2.arrayofC[i];
           double start=c.start;
           double end=c.end;
           int j=c.arrayofD.size;
           while (j>0)
           {
              D d=c.arrayofD[j];
              CString Name=d.Name;
              ...
              j--;
           }
           ....
      }
}
```

This makes the code very messy and it's obvious that there is a tight coupling between the model and the view. How can I make them highly independent to each other so as to ensure the maintainability or scalability of my application.

Comment: Well, a view should be tight coupled to the underlying model data, shouldn't it??

Comment: Maybe I didn't express it appropriately. What I concern is that when I want to change the Model a lot, I also need to change the view a lot  as the model exposes too much details to the view.

Comment: Are you actually sure, needing such a deep inheritance model, i.e. you are sure every `D1`, `G2`, etc. actually ***is a*** `A`? A model design like such is probably seriously flawed.

Comment: Yeah, in my model objects on each level does have a belong-to relationship between that on the higher level. And all those objects including the root object A are extended from a base object because they have some common attributes and methods.

Comment: That's way not enough evidence they really require a _is a_ relationship. Flawed probably as mentioned. Go back to your requirements.

Comment: From my guts it feels you are more looking after a [Composite Design Pattern](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite&ved=0CEgQFjAIahUKEwigveO-vuDHAhUE83IKHY_OBVE&usg=AFQjCNFdbwBaXUd0WLaRAvA2U7Em9k-oVg&sig2=Ak-9UvXftSe7XUSpEVSa4A) for your model, rather than an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think you are misinterpreting the code/diagram; from the code it does not appear that any inheritance is used at all, instead it just seems that he uses composition extensively.

Comment: @MatthieuM. May be you're right I'm misinterpreting a non UML standards diagram, but as asked for it seems to be an inheritance hierarchy. OP stated so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: From my understanding, all his objects inherit from a single base: `A: Base`, `B: Base`, `C: Base`, ... and then `A` has a `B1` attribute and a `B2` attribute, etc... To be honest though I have no idea what to do with this question; there are plenty of potential advices, but it's unclear how any will fit the particular needs of the OP. I am afraid that the question has been so abstracted it's too generic.

Comment: @MatthieuM. _" I am afraid that the question has been so abstracted it's too generic. "_ Same for me, it seems not possible to give a concise answer.

Comment: I have removed the inheritance part which really isn't what I'm focusing on in this question, so don't worry about it anymore.